# django+ send email in html with django-registration

Tags: django, email, django-templates, django-registration

im using django-registration, all is fine, the confirmation email was sending in plain text, but know im fixed and is sending in html, but i have a litter problem... the html code is showing:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/accounts/activate/46656b86eefc490baf4170134429d83068642139/">http://www. example.com/accounts/activate/46656b86eefc490baf4170134429d83068642139/</a>
```

and i dont need to show the html code like the ...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend sending both a text version and an html version. Look in the models.py of the django-registration for :

```
send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.user.email])
```

and instead do something like from the docs http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Comment: Yes Paul, thans for replay, but is not working i did in that way and nothing...but now is ok :) , now just a put the link without <a ...

Comment: That will send a text email that some clients will create links for. If you ever need more interesting html, you will have to do what I recommended.

Comment: yes, i tryed but dont work, but is ok :) ill try a litter  more :)

Answer (score 27):

To avoid patching django-registration, you should extend the RegistrationProfile model with [proxy=True](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models):

**models.py**

```
class HtmlRegistrationProfile(RegistrationProfile):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def send_activation_email(self, site):
        """Send the activation mail"""
        from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
        from django.template.loader import render_to_string

        ctx_dict = {'activation_key': self.activation_key,
                    'expiration_days': settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS,
                    'site': site}
        subject = render_to_string('registration/activation_email_subject.txt',
                                   ctx_dict)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())

        message_text = render_to_string('registration/activation_email.txt', ctx_dict)
        message_html = render_to_string('registration/activation_email.html', ctx_dict)

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message_text, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.user.email])
        msg.attach_alternative(message_html, "text/html")
        msg.send()
```

And in your registration backend, just use **HtmlRegistrationProfile** instead of **RegistrationProfile**.

Comment: How do i register the new profile with the registration backend?

Comment: How do I set the backend to HtmlRegistration profile instead of RegistrationProfile?

Comment: Do we have to make an other registration backend that uses our new proxy Model ?

Comment: How you can set the new default?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and the registration package is no longer maintained. Just in case somebody still wants this.
The additional steps wrt to the answer of @bpierre are:
 - subclass the RegistrationView, i.e. your app's views.py

```
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
...
def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
    ...
    new_user = HtmlRegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email, password, site)
```

- in your urls.py change the view to the sub-classed view, i.e.
 - List item

```
url(r'accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm), name='registration_register'),'
```

Answer (score 0):

[This guy have extended the defaultBackend](https://github.com/huseyinyilmaz/django-registration-extended-backend) enabling us to add an HTML version of the activation email.

Specifically, the alternate version job is done [here](https://github.com/huseyinyilmaz/django-registration-extended-backend/blob/master/extendedregistrationbackend/extended/__init__.py#L91)

I managed to use the backend part successfully