# Django registration alternatives

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-registration

I'm looking at [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/). It's in alpha 0.8, and hasn't been updated for 12/13 months. But it seems this is what most people use? I'm just wondering if there is a production standard package out there for managing users on a django site, or do people tend to roll their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't been updated because it works very well ;)
Frankly, you really should use this package, along with django-profiles, django-invitation...

The only problem (for me) is the lack of example templates in django-registration
But you can look at [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/cliff/django-registration-templates/overview) to get some

Comment: What about support for HTML emails?

Comment: SO is your friend : [adding HTML emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325983/django-send-email-in-html-with-django-registration)

Answer (score 1):

Try **django-registration-redux**, a maintained fork of django-registration:

- https://github.com/macropin/django-registration
- https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: django-registration is being maintained again:
https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a GAE app that is going to use its own registration module. It works using AJAX, can create new users in database, send codes for verifying new users and recovering existing users by email. I am almost done with this module and I am sure it won't take much time to configured for using with Django models for works with database. The important thing you could take from there is the concept of the registration/verification/restoring processes. Please feel free to clone the module from [here](https://github.com/skible/skible/tree/master/skible) and participate in developing it. You can also ping me if you have any questions, I will help with pleasure! Thanks.