# Django - authentication, registration with email confirmation

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

I'm looking at the API for authentication

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/

I can't seem to find information on simple user registration form that would send confirmation email as it is the usual way on web sites.

I guess I could do this:

1) Display a form
2) User enters info and submits
3) Save user as inactive, with a confirmation code
4) Send a link with confirmation code
5) User clicks a confirmation link and becomes active

It doesn't seem that difficult but I have a feeling this might be done already, and also there are quite a few edge cases that would need to be considered.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not built into Django. There is a reusable app called [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), which will fit your needs.

An app called [django-registration](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration) used to be recommended, but that is now unmaintained and out of date.

*Editor note*: django-registration is not unmaintained as of December 2016.

Comment: I'm also checking the Pinaxproject.com but it's a bit overwhelming. It does support registration among other useful things.

Comment: Pinax works, but from my experience, I do not recommend it. It is doing too many things in its own idiosyncratic way, and then if you ever want to change anything, you'd wish you'd have written it from scratch.

Comment: The app django-registration has maintenance in https://github.com/macropin/django-registration

Answer (score 9):

While [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) used to be the registration system du jour, it has been [abandoned by the maintainer](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/63/django-16-compatibility-fix-auth-views/diff#comment-1646840) and [doesn't work on Django 1.6 without patching](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/63/django-16-compatibility-fix-auth-views/diff).

Try maybe [django-allauth](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-allauth/) - I would have used it if I had known about it when I was looking. (As it turned out, I found this question first and used django-registration, wasting a lot of time.)

EDIT 10/2016: Looks like django-registration is maintained again. It's on GitHub now: https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration

Comment: Nice I was looking at the django-registration package; however it looked unmaintained, which made me wary. But django-allauth looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- Define a function to activate the user (i. e. def
  activate(request))

  - Configure in the url.py the route to that function (i.e /activate/)
- Create a form to register user
- Create the post function to create the user

  - When you create the user set field 'is_active' to 0.
  - In the same function send the email with a link inside, this link must have the target as the configured route