# Django - authentication, registration with email confirmation (2019)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I was looking to create a authentication, registration, password reset and email confirmation using Django.

Workflow:

- Displays form to enter username, email address, password,
- sends verification email, to email to be verified.
- user is inactive until link verification is complete.
- option to reset password through this page

I found this question posted in 2011 
[Django - authentication, registration with email confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488384/django-authentication-registration-with-email-confirmation)

Summary:

- [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), last commit 25 days ago
- [django-registration](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration), last comitt 4 months ago
- any others?

Questions:

- Since it is 2019 I thought to ask again and see what people recommend and use in 2019?
- which do recommend and why? (easy of use, documentation, industry standard, involved community? etc.. )

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is opinion based, so it will most likely get flagged as such - but I will try to answer anyways.

`django-allauth` is still, in my opinion, the best overall registration workflow for someone looking for *social* login or login with extra capabilities, such as email verification (which you seem to need). For regular login capabilities it is overkill, and you can just use the default [django authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/) for that. Don't forget you can always extend basic django authentication using [custom authentication](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef)

If you are going to use django to create an API that serves react, swift, etc, you can also use `django-rest-framework` with an authentication package such as [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) to handle multiple token-based sessions.