# Django-registration: how to include a custom backend?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I created a custom backend to have activation emails in html without editing django-registration code

(ref. [django+ send email in html with django-registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325983/django-send-email-in-html-with-django-registration), last answer)

this is the backend, stored in `core/registration/backends/htmldefault/__init__.py`, like DefaultBackend that is stored in `registration/backends/__init__.py`

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from core.models import HtmlRegistrationProfile

class HtmlDefaultBackend(object):
   #etc same as DefaultBackend but using HtmlRegistrationProfile instead of RegistrationProfile
```

and this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'core.registration.backends.htmldefault.HtmlDefaultBackend','form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    #...
)
```

But i get

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/register/

Error loading registration backend core.registration.backends.htmldefault: "No module named registration.backends.htmldefault"
```

thrown by `/registration/backends/__init__.py in get_backend, line 27`

What i'm asking is.. is it possible to have a custom django-registration backend outside the registration package? Or it must live under /registration/backends/ like simple and default backends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

1. Check if all your folders (core, registration, backends,
   htmldefault) have `__init__.py` (can be empty).
2. Core folder is in project directory?

Comment: 2 stupid errors.. first your point 1, i didn't created the __init__.py in every folder (that was a very bad miss), then that path created conflicts with registration package.. now everything is working, thanks